# Does the Sleep spell use current or maximum hit points?

Tags: spells, dnd-5e

On Page 101 of the D&D 5e Basic PDF the effect of a Sleep Spell is stated as follows.

> This spell sends creatures into a magical slumber.
>   Roll 5d8; the total is how many **hit points of creatures**
>   this spell can affect. Creatures within 20 feet of
>   a point you choose within range are affected in
>   ascending order of their current hit points (ignoring
>   unconscious creatures).

Does hit points of creature refer to their **current** hit points or their **maximum** hit points.

Maximum hit points are defined as the number of hit point a undamaged creature or character has. Note page 10 of the D&D 5e Basic PDF.

> Each time you gain a level, you gain 1 additional Hit Die. Roll that
>   Hit Die, add your Constitution modifier to the roll, and add the total
>   to your hit point maximum.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's current hit points. It says so in the last sentence.

> Creatures within 20 feet of a point you choose wthin range are affect in ascending order of their **current hit points** (ignoring unconscious creatures).

I added that emphasis. So if you roll a 5 (a very unlikely roll), you affect a creature or group of creatures with 5 *current* hit points or less, starting with the weakest. Once the total *current* HP of the affect creatures is 5 or more, you don't affect anything else.

If it were total hit points, this spell would be more-or-less useless.

Comment: So basically, the closer you are to death, the easier you are to put to sleep, makes sense to me :)

Answer (score 8):

It would seem logical that the spell affects the creatures in view of their **current hit points.** The first quote you've used even seems to say so: *in ascending order of their current hit points* -- and this is further supported by the addition of *ignoring unconscious creatures*, because why would the spell ignore them if it was their maximum hit points that mattered instead of their current one? :)

Comment: I assume unconscious creatures are ignored because they're not awake, which may or may not have anything to do with their hit points. Remember, 0 hit points makes you unconscious, but being unconscious doesn't mean you have 0 hit points. You may just be sleeping...